# Adding a string to a list using augmented assignment

Tags: python, string, list, augmented-assignment

```
>>> b = []
>>> c = '1234'
>>> b += c
>>> b
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>>
```

What is happening here? This should not work, right? Or am I missing something obvious?

```
>>> b = []
>>> c = '1234'
>>> b + c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    b + c
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
>>>
```

Then `a += b`  is not always equivalent to `a = a + b` ?

Comment: Is this behaviour still present in Python 3.x? I always found it irritating that a standard library type breaks the general contract that `a += b` <=> `a = a + b` (without affecting any other references to the original `a` value).

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: unfortunately, it's still present in Python 3.2.1.

Comment: I was checking it in python 3.2, yes. I found the issue looking at a beginner code that was producing wrong results. I could not find any reference to this specific behavior in `Learning Python`. I checked PEP203 and it says that `__iadd__` is used but also they say that `__iadd__` is the inplace `__add__` that is not the case in this case... Maybe someone could explain the rational beneath this behavior or point/link to some discussion about that? I understand from Karl's comment that there is people concerned about it

Answer (score 18):

Strings are iterable: the elements are the string's characters. When you add an iterable to a list, the iterable's *elements* get appended to the list.

Either of the following will do what you're expecting (i.e. append the string, not extend the list with the string's characters):

```
b += [c]
```

or

```
b.append(c)
```

Answer (score 10):

The `+=` operator *extends* a list instead of appending to it:

```
>>> b = []
>>> c = "1234"
>>> b.append(c)
>>> b
['1234']
>>> b.extend(c)
>>> b
['1234', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> b += c
>>> b
['1234', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> b += [c]
>>> b
['1234', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1234']
```

Comment: do you know a source of documentation on the effect of these operators (`+`, `+=`) for iterables/sequences/... ?

Comment: @moooeeeep - in [the table in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) - you can also see how it happens in the actual source.

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer not to the original question (which I think has been adequately answered), but to the numerous questions that have been asked in the comments about the semantics of augmented assignment (`+=` and similar operations).

In a nutshell: Augmented assignment works differently for mutable types than for immutable ones.

`str`, `tuple`, and the numeric types, among others, are immutable. The contents of a tuple cannot be changed once it has been created, so you get this behavior:

```
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> b = a
>>> a += (3, 4)
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> b
(1, 2)
```

`str` has the same semantics. Basically, `a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b` if `a` is immutable.

Most other types, including `list`, are mutable. A list's contents *can* be changed in place, and augmented assignment does exactly that. Hence:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = a
>>> a += [3, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Whereas if the third line were replaced with `a = a + [3, 4]`, a new list would be created and `b` would be `[1, 2]`.

For a user-defined class, the semantics depend on how it was implemented, but this is how it's supposed to be done per PEP 203.

Comment: This is a really good observation. `a` and `b` share the same memory address until `a` is evaluated on the left hand side of an assignment operator? Could you include that?

Answer (score 2):

A string is a sequence of characters.  The list operation `+=` takes any sequence and appends each of the sequence's elements to the list.

(Actually `+=` takes any iterable.)

Comment: `+` is a different operator than `+=`.

Comment: I know, it is called augmented assigment and it is defined to be equivalent to a = a + b (see PEP203). Taking this definition strictly drive me to a wrong expectation. That is what surprised me (probably I never dared to add a list to a string in my python code so I never collided with this before). Should not be `In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess` ?.

Comment: Nowhere in PEP-203 does it claim that `a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`.

Answer (score 2):

+= is syntactic sugar for extend, but + is just list concatenation. If you extend, you'll iterate over the argument, which in this case is a string. But you can't concatenate a string to a list, hence + fails.

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect? If you want to add **c** as string you must to do:

```
b.append(c)
```

Cheers!

Comment: But as Tim explained above the behavior of += is not the same that +

Comment: please, see comment on Tim post.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, the += operator on the list will retrieve c's iterator, which will yield the individual characters in order. If you intended to add the actual string to the list, yielding the result ['1234'], you can use b.append('1234') instead.