# Array.extend(string) adds every character instead of just the string

Tags: python, string, extend

I am trying to extend an element to a list in Python, however, instead of extending the string in the index 'i' it extends every character of the string in the index 'i'.

For example I have a list called 'strings' with just a string 'string1' and an empty list called 'final_list'.

I want to extend the first element of 'strings' to the 'final_list', so I do `final_list.extend(strings[0])`. But instead of the 'final_list' to end with a length of 1, corresponding to the string inserted, the list ends up with a length of 7.

If it helps, this is my code:

```
con = connect()
    i = 0
    new_files = []
    while i < len(files):
        info_file = obter_info(con, files[i])
        if info_file [5] == 0: #file not processed
            new_files.append(files[i])
        i += 1
```

Does anyone know how can I make this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a string to a list using augmented assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322792/adding-a-string-to-a-list-using-augmented-assignment)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `extend` method takes an iterable as an argument, unpacks that iterable and adds each element individually to the list upon which it is called.  In your case, you are "extending" a list with a string.  A string is an iterable.  As such, the string is "unpacked" and each character is added separately:

```
>>> d = []
>>> d.extend('hello')
>>> print(d)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

If you simply want to add one element of a list to another list, then use `append`.  Otherwise, surround the string in a list and repeat the extend:

```
>>> d = []
>>> d.extend(['hello'])
>>> print(d)
['hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

try that one:

```
final_list.extend([strings[0]])
```

or:

```
final_list.append(strings[0])
```